# JS array - weird values with "for in" loop

Tags: javascript

Have JS array w/o keys

code 1

```
var psnb_arr=['14-007', '14-008', '14-009'];
console.log(psnb_arr);

//output in firebug: ["14-007", "14-008", "14-009"]
```

code 2

```
for (var i in psnb_arr) {
  var psnb=psnb_arr[i];
  console.log(i+'-'+psnb);
}

//wierd output in firebug:
0-14-007
1-14-008
2-14-009

copy-function (start,length){start=start||0;if(start<0)start=this.length+start;

length=length||(this.length-start);var newArray=[];for(var i=0;i<length;i++)newArray[i]=this[start++];return newArray;}

remove-function (item){var i=0;var len=this.length;while(i<len){if(this[i]===item){this.splice(i,1);len--;}else{i++;}} return this;}

contains-function (item,from){return this.indexOf(item,from)!=-1;}


...
```

what is this wierd output in firebug for console.log within the loop?
I mean the text that is coming right after "2-14-009" - "copy-function..."

Comment: what is so wired about it, its coming correct output.

Comment: i = the "0-" on the first output, just as it's written in your code.

Comment: Your "object without keys" is just an array.  It *does* have keys, they are numeric.

Comment: I mean the text that is coming right after "2-14-009" - "copy-function..."

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle to reproduce your problem? You dont have this in another browser? I just get the array output, not the other stuff. What version Firefox / firebug are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have an object, nor do you have an associative array (these no not exist in JavaScript).  What you have in a "normal" (numeric) array.  It *does* have keys; the array indexes (that's where the `0-`, etc. are coming from).

The problem you are seeing is because you are using `for...in` on an array.  This is a bad practice.  The `Array` prototype can contain properties (sometimes JavaScript libraries add these), so you are iterating over *all* of those properties, not just the array values.

You want to use a normal `for` loop here.

```
for(var i = 0; i < psnb_arr.length; i++){
    var psnb=psnb_arr[i];
    console.log(i+'-'+psnb);
}
```

Comment: @putvande: Yeah, I'm fully aware.  I explained *exactly* why that's happening and how to fix it.  What's the problem?

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about "sometimes JavaScript libraries add these"

Comment: @ihtus: Are you using something like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) or an [ES5 shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim)?  That's normally where this comes from.  They add methods to `Array.prototype`.

Comment: as another option hasOwnProperty can fix the issue above, but anyway @RocketHazmat explanation is OK

Comment: @EugeneP: Yes, you can add `hasOwnProperty` to the `for..in` loop, but it's easier (and I think better practice) to just use a normal `for` loop (or `.forEach()`). :-)

Comment: @rocket: yes, it's under joomla that is using prototype.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, yeah. totally agreee :)